# Post Thumbnail missing when using webp format while sharing

Tags: post-meta, post-thumbnails, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a problem when I upload a featured image for my post in jpg format, I get the featured image's thumbnail while sharing my post through any kind of messenger e.g whatsapp etc. But when I try to upload the featured image in webp format. My post thumbnail gets missing while sharing it. As far as I have studied about it till last year og:image for webp wasn't supported in wordpress. Is it still the same. Is there any way? Any wordpress hooks that I can use to get webp format supported too. Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Does the HTML contain the `og:image` part with the .webp URL? Sinds rather like the clients (e.g. whatsapp) are not supporting the image now while from WP side most likely it is the same for jpeg und webp and just outputs the correct URL.

Comment: @kero Well that can be the case because when we upload featured image in jpeg format post thumbnail shows on all clients whatsapp etc. In webp format post thumbnail shows on facebook but not on other chat platforms